# Add Row to DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net

I have a DataGridView that is not connected to a database.

I manually insert N columns into the gridview and then I want to add the rows.
I was wondering if I can do that using something similar to

```
char[] rowValues = new char[N];
// fill rowValues here

DataGridView.Rows.Add(rowValue);
```

And then have each element in rowValue appear under a different column.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a 2 dimensional array you can just set the datasource of your grid to be that array and call databind.

Or the long way would be to have a nested loop and set the value of each of the cells for each row.

an example of the long way is

```
        Dim dgvRow As New DataGridViewRow
        Dim dgvCell As DataGridViewCell

        dgvCell = New DataGridViewTextBoxCell()
        dgvCell.Value = "anis"
        dgvRow.Cells.Add(dgvCell)

        dgvCell = New DataGridViewTextBoxCell()
        dgvCell.Value = "khan"
        dgvRow.Cells.Add(dgvCell)

        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(dgvRow)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess there is no way around it then. I expected it to support some kind of method similar to the one in my question. Oh well...